# Convert the below date to datetime and then change its display format using the .dt module

Tags: pandas, datetime

Convert the below date to datetime and then change its display format using the .dt module

Date = "15Dec1989"

Result : "Friday, 15 Dec 89"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean from **15Dec1989** to **Friday, 15 Dec 89** not **Friday, 15 Dec 98**. If yes, this is my answer:

```
pd.to_datetime("15Dec1989").strftime('%A, %d %b %y')
```

Hope it is useful for you.